# How does IPv6 compensate for the removed header fields in IPv4?

Tags: ipv6, network-protocols, ipv4

The header fields:

- IHL
- Identification
- Flags
- Fragment Offset
- Header Checksum
- Options
- Padding

Are removed in IPv6, does this mean a deprecation of functionality or is the functionality just transferred to other header elements.

Comment: IPv4 and IPv6 are completely different protocols, with different needs. For example, why doesn't IPv4 have the `Node` or `Socket` fields of IPX?

Comment: Start by reading [RFC 8200](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8200).

Comment: Read up on the concept of extension headers